# Reagent state not updating after setInterval

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have this reagent component that uses setInterval to change its state:

```
(defn foo []
  (let [value (atom 1)]
    (js/setInterval (fn [] (reset! value (rand-int 100)) (println @value)) 1000)
    (fn []
      [:p @value])))
```

I can see the value being printed, a different one each time, but the html doesn't change. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is that I should have been using a `reagent.core/atom` instead of an `atom`.